# CollectionViewCell didn't appear at the first time of running

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm working with UICollectionView in Swift and encountered this weird bug that I didn't know where It came from.

So I have a normal set up for my collection view:

```
func setupCollectionView() {
    ColorTagViewCell.registerCellByNib(self.colorTagCollection)
    self.colorTagCollection.delegate = self
    self.colorTagCollection.dataSource = self
}
```

Implementation of function delegate:

```
extension EventViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colorStringList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = ColorTagViewCell.loadCell(self.colorTagCollection, path: indexPath) as? ColorTagViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell()}
        cell.setupViewForCell(colorString: colorStringList[indexPath.row], state: colorSelection[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

When I run the application the collection view cell didn't appear although I have set default background color for each cell
[image: The cells didn't appear on collection view]

But when I click on any cell, It would show up and look something like this:
[image: The cell appeared after click]

I have not implemented any cell interaction method or clicking or that kinds of stuff. I don't know what this bug is and I have tried to fix it for a day now and haven't got any luck.
I also call reloadData() in viewDidLoad() and debug the UI and notice that my collection view is still there it just not appear with color.

My ColorTagViewCell class, where I format and setup the cell:

```
class ColorTagViewCell: BaseCLCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var outerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.roundedView(views: [self.outerView, self.innerView])
    }

    func roundedView(views: [UIView]) {
        views.forEach { (view) in
            view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2
            view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    func setupViewForCell(colorString: String, state: Bool) {
        self.outerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromHexString(hex: colorString)
        self.innerView.isHidden = state
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show where you set background colors of these cells, and where you generally format them? Maybe they are there but invisible.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Zzx7PhV, here is the code where I format and setup the cell, don't mind about innerView because it is hidden, I commented that line of code before but It didn't help, as you can see that I set a background color for each of them, but it just not appear when i run the application, it just appear after I click on it. https://ibb.co/xqY7QNc, another picture when I capture the UI, the cell does have a background color as you can see in the right panel, this is really weird when they didn't show up, but they are still on the view

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code as text

Comment: I just edited my question to include the code of my CollectionViewCell class, where I format and setup the cell. Is there anything else I should add to clarify more about my problem ?

Comment: Can you show where do you set up the arrays used? Also, where do you call setupCollectionView()

Comment: This is the two arrays I use to set up my cells 
"var colorStringList = ["33CC99", "F2C94C", "EB5757", "FD8686", "56CCF2", "9B51E0"]"
"var colorSelection = Array(repeating: true, count: 6)"
Just ignore the colorSelection for now, It just a boolean arrays I will use later to implement my logic. And the setupCollectionView() is called in the viewDidLoad(). I have tested those delegte function by print something in those function, and it worked. The problem here is just why my cell have white color and didn't show up on the view although I have set background color for it

Comment: var colorSelection = Array(repeating: true, count: 6)  should it be false? since it will set it hidden in setupViewForCell - isHidden will be true

Comment: Actually my cells have 2 UIView, the innerView and outerView, https://ibb.co/Hqgh37D, u can see in this photo, the view I hide is the innerView the smaller circle. The thing is the outerView (the bigger circle) didn't show up on the view, it just appear when I click on the cell as you can see in the question's image even though I haven't implemented any interaction method for my cells. Something weird happend and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem, the bug was caused by the ColorTagViewCell class

This is the code I updated to fix the bug:

```
class ColorTagViewCell: BaseCLCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var outerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func roundedView(views: [UIView]) {
        views.forEach { (view) in
            view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2
            view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    func setupViewForCell(colorString: String, state: Bool) {
        self.outerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromHexString(hex: colorString)
        self.innerView.isHidden = state
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.roundedView(views: [self.outerView, self.innerView])
    }
}
```

I just add "layoutIfNeeded()" function and it solved the problem. As my code show, I want to fill the cell background color by using my delegate function cellForItemAt() with the method setupViewForCell(), at the same time I want to round its layer with the roundedView() method, so I think that it doesn't know what to do first because the view render asynchronously. After I set background color for my cell, I use the "layoutIfNeeded()" function and then I round the cell, now it works just fine.